# Undefined variable: $ Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

This is the code from CategoriesController:

```
 public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('/home', compact('categories'));
}
```

And this is the code that I'm writing to the `home.blade.php`

```
                @foreach($categories as $cat)
                @endforeach
```

And then in `home.blade.php`

I'm getting this error: `Undefined variable: categories`

Why this happening ? Everything works fine with Articles but not categories and the code is the same.

Home.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

     <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Categories</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

                          @foreach($categories as $cat)
                          <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="articles/category/{{  }}">News</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>                          
                          @endforeach
   </div>
      </div>     
    </div>


  @if(count($articles))

    @foreach($articles as $article)

<div class="panel panel-default col-md-8">
  <div class="panel-heading">

  <h3>{{ $article->title }}</h3>
   <small>posted by <a href="users/{{ $article->author->name }}">{{ $article->author->name }}</a> {{ $article->created_at }}</small>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  {!! str_limit($article->body, 1000) !!} 
    <hr>
  <a href="{{ url('/articles/'.$article->slug) }}">Read More</a>   
  </div>
</div>

        @endforeach
    @else
        <h1>No articles at the moment.</h1>
    @endif
    <br>
    {!! $articles->render() !!}
@stop
```

Comment: Please verify no other view is there like `index.php` instead of `index.blade.php`. and make sure that controller returns tha value. ie, `return $categories` before `return view ...`

Comment: Try removing `/` from your view path and also can you post your whole view `home.blade.php`?

Comment: Removing "/" doesnt work. I added home.blade.php @IvankaTodorova

Comment: It looks OK to me. Are you sure that the variable error comes from that exact view `home.blade.php`?

Comment: I dont think so. If I make view let's say to "contact" page then the same error occurs, I dont get what could be the problem

Comment: There two routes:
Route::get('/home', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'CategoriesController@index');
That's the problem. If I one of these router then everything working but without articles or categories

Comment: Just as an unrelated side note, your view could use `@forelse @empty` rather than `@if @foreach`. A nice little added control structure to do what you're doing there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two routes

```
Route::get('/home', 'ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'CategoriesController@index');
```

Which means when you visit /home, only ArticlesController@index is fired, not both.

This means that the `$categories` variable used in the view is not populated because your `index()` method in CategoriesController is intended to do this but is never called.

Therefore you need to do something like this

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $articles   = Article::all();

    return view('/home', compact('articles', 'categories'));
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you sir! Everything is working like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

try to use

```
return View::make('/home')->with(compact('categories'));
```

instead of

```
return view('/home', compact('categories'));
```

Comment: Either syntax is valid, and always has been.

Answer (score -1):

I insert this in the top of my @foreach

```
 <?php
     use App\models\PersonalContact;
     $data = PersonalContact::all();
 ?>
```

or this before @foreach add @if statement like this

```
 @if (count($data) > 0)
            @foreach ($data as $bloginfo)
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td class="sorting_1">{{$bloginfo->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bloginfo->description}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bloginfo->email}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bloginfo->phone}}</td>
                    <td><img src="{{url('images/'.$bloginfo->image)}}" alt="" width="100px" height="100px"></td>
                <td><a href="{{url('admin/{admin}/personalcontact/create')}}" class="btn btn-app"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Add</a> | <a href="{{url('admin/{admin}/personalcontact/{personalcontact}/edit')}}" class="btn btn-app"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Edit</a> | <a class="btn btn-app"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

```
return view('/home', compact('categories'));
```

The problem was `$categories` on compact method, you must use like a string

Comment: It looks like that is already what they have in the example they posted.